# Uploading video to youtube stops with no error

Tags: php, google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, google-api-php-client

I'll like to upload videos to youtube, I have correctly the token, but never uploads it , gives no error... it stops execution at line $status = $media->nextChunk($chunk);

Here is my code:

```
   if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
      try { 
        $videoData['title'] = "test";
        $videoData['description'] = "descripcio";
        $videoData['tags'] = "tag1, tgag2, tag3";
        $videoData['privacy'] = "https://XXXXXX.com/privacy.html";
        $videoPath = "/Compilations/u4vmacx0-6685l2bm5aan67nknwbp-wm.mp4";

        // Create a snippet with title, description, tags and category ID 
        // Create an asset resource and set its snippet metadata and type. 
        // This example sets the video's title, description, keyword tags, and 
        // video category. 
        $snippet = new Google_Service_YouTube_VideoSnippet(); 
        $snippet->setTitle($videoData['title']); 
        $snippet->setDescription($videoData['description']); 
        $snippet->setTags(explode(",", $videoData['tags'])); 
     
        // Numeric video category. See 
        // https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videoCategories/list 
        $snippet->setCategoryId("22"); 
     
        // Set the video's status to "public". Valid statuses are "public", 
        // "private" and "unlisted". 
        $status = new Google_Service_YouTube_VideoStatus(); 
        $status->privacyStatus = $videoData['privacy']; 
     
        // Associate the snippet and status objects with a new video resource. 
        $video = new Google_Service_YouTube_Video(); 
        $video->setSnippet($snippet); 
        $video->setStatus($status); 
     
        // Specify the size of each chunk of data, in bytes. Set a higher value for 
        // reliable connection as fewer chunks lead to faster uploads. Set a lower 
        // value for better recovery on less reliable connections. 
        $chunkSizeBytes = 50 * 1024 * 1024;     // era 1
     
        // Setting the defer flag to true tells the client to return a request which can be called 
        // with ->execute(); instead of making the API call immediately. 
        $client->setDefer(true); 
     
        // Create a request for the API's videos.insert method to create and upload the video. 
        $insertRequest = $youtube->videos->insert("status,snippet", $video); 
     
        // Create a MediaFileUpload object for resumable uploads. 
        $media = new Google_Http_MediaFileUpload( 
            $client, 
            $insertRequest, 
            'video/*', 
            null, 
            true, 
            $chunkSizeBytes 
        ); 
        $media->setFileSize(filesize($videoPath)); 
     
        // Read the media file and upload it chunk by chunk. 
        $status = false; 
        $handle = fopen($videoPath, "rb"); 

        while (!$status && !feof($handle)) { 
          echo "YES 1";
            $chunk = fread($handle, $chunkSizeBytes); 
          echo "YES 2";
            $status = $media->nextChunk($chunk); 
          echo "NOT REACHED";    // NEVER REACHES THAT LINE
        } 

        fclose($handle); 
        // If you want to make other calls after the file upload, set setDefer back to false 
        $client->setDefer(false); 

        if(!empty($status['id'])){ 
            // Uploaded youtube video info 
            $video_title = $status['snippet']['title']; 
            $video_desc = $status['snippet']['description']; 
            $video_tags = implode(",",$status['snippet']['tags']); 
            $youtube_video_id = $status['id']; 
             
             
            $status = 'success'; 
            $statusMsg = 'Video has been uploaded to YouTube successfully!'; 

            echo $status. " ". $statusMsg;
        } 
      } catch (Google_Service_Exception $e) { 
        $statusMsg = 'A service error occurred: <code>'.$e->getMessage().'</code>'; 
      } catch (Google_Exception $e) { 
        $statusMsg = 'An client error occurred: <code>'.$e->getMessage().'</code>'; 
        $statusMsg .= '<br/>Please reset session <a href="logout.php">Logout</a>'; 
      } 


    }
```

when executing the code, it outputs "YES 1YES 2" , never reaches echo "NOT REACHED"; line.... why? Can I add an exception or something to tell me the error?
The video file exists and the program finds it, as the file size is correct.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very hard to spot the mistake with no logs or exceptions, but how about `$videoData['privacy'] = "https://XXXXXX.com/privacy.html"`?

Privacy status can be `PUBLIC | PRIVATE | UNLISTED`, and on 'normal' accounts it can be only `PUBLIC`. Maybe that could be mistake?

Comment: Yes!! Was that!! I thought it was the link to privacy policy :(